# How to store it in a variable?

Tags: javascript

I need to store the ReCaptcha code in a JavaScript variable and then dynamically show the captcha (in a dynamically created DIV). The problem is the following code cannot be stored in a variable:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k="></script><noscript><iframe src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=" height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe><br/><textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40"></textarea><input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field" value="manual_challenge"/></noscript>`

I get the error in Firebug: `unterminated string literal`. How to make it work?

Comment: The reason Firebug thinks the string's unterminated (as should any standards-compliant browser) is because (1) you're using quotation marks inside the string, which need to be escaped with backslashes (exactly as @Rob mentioned), and (2) you can't include HTML tags inside JavaScript literals. @Horos's answer has what you're looking for to get around this (which is why I didn't post an answer of my own).

Answer (score 1):

You are probably storing it in a string using `"` as the delimiters, which is clashing with the `"` used on the attributes' value delimiters.

Try using single quote (`'`), or escape each `"` with a backslash (`\"`) to have it treated literally.

Answer (score 1):

```
var s = '<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k="></script><noscript><iframe src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=" height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe><br/><textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40"></textarea><input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field" value="manual_challenge"/></noscript>'
```